# Is it possible to design view with uiscrollview in storyboard with checked auto layout?

Tags: layout, uiview, uiscrollview, scroll, autolayout

Good day! 
i have hierarchy:

> view-scroll view - [set of elements: labels, textfields, etc.].
>
> Height of view is more than default size. i've added to scrollview in storyboard key with *contentSize*, set *top and left constraint*, in **viewDidLoad** i set
>
> **self.scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;**

but in emulator scrolling is not working...( if i uncheck auto layout scrolling is working. but i need it checked. 
So question is it possible to design view with uiscrollview in storyboard with checked auto layout?
thanks everybody for answering!=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution: for correct working scrolling you need ONLY add constraint horizontal and vertical spaces + spaces from top and bottom Layout guide=)
stay on scroll view - touch button "Add missing constraints"... after this constraints will be added automatically...=) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible. You should add constraints to your scrollview.

If you add constraints to your scroll view.

- You don't need to set frame to your scroll view.
- You don't need to set the content size and content size will be
  automatically calculated in runtime based on your constraints.

Comment: i've done... added constraints, delete frame size and content size but nothing happened... Scrolling not works...(

Comment: may be i've added not correct constraint: vertical and horizontal spaces?

Comment: Yes, you need to add correct constraints for your requirement. Otherwise, it won't work.